# Can DNS Geolocation Routing be used together with Amazon CloudFront?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, geolocation, amazon-route53

Is  feasibility of having 2 CNAME records loading different resources depending on the location of the requestor? Ideally we'd have cdn.abc.com load cloudfront.abc.com when being requested anywhere outside of China, in China this would serve abccdn.ccindex.com.

In this scenario would the host header be passed to the CDN as 'cdn.abc.com' or the CNAME mapped address?

Comment: Is your desire to serve **different content**, or to simply serve content **closer to the users**? CloudFront caches content close to users (including Beijing; Shenzhen; Shanghai; Zhongwei).

Comment: Thanks John Rotenstein , want to server the content closer to user  depending on the location of the requester.can you confirm that would the host header be passed to the CDN as 'cdn.abc.com' or the CNAME mapped address?

Comment: Amazon CloudFront can cache _static content_ closer to the user. Would this not be sufficient for your use-case in China? It would avoid having to duplicate infrastructure. Are you serving a mostly static website, or is it a compute-intensive offering that requires low-latency (eg responding to API calls)? It would theoretically be possible to put Route 53 geo routing in front of CloudFront. This might help: [amazon web services - AWS Cloudfront with Geolocation policy vs Route53 - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54003091/aws-cloudfront-with-geolocation-policy-vs-route53)

Comment: Yes, John we serving a mostly static website,so in our scenario for China it would serve abccdn.ccindex.com,  would the host header be passed to the CDN as 'cdn.abc.com' or the CNAME mapped address? can you please explain a bit to understand better !!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to

- Create a Domain Name in Route 53
- Use [Geolocation routing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy.html#routing-policy-geo) to send Chinese traffic to a location in China
- Use the **default routing** option to send other (worldwide) traffic to **CloudFront**

```
example.com --> Route 53 --> Geolocation routing sends China users to China region
                         --> Other users sent to CloudFront CNAME
                                   --> CloudFront points to Origin site (not in China)
```