# Can you use one domain for multiple cloudfront distributions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-elb

I have created 3 cloudfront instances for users to use a site in 3 different regions (Asia, Europe, NA) for one website.  Is there a way I can use one domain that would automatically send them to the cloudfront instance depending on the user's geographic location.  I was thinking maybe I could do this via load-balancing.  If its not possible I'm going to just create 3 different domains per region (example-na.com ,example-eu.com, example-as.com)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS Cloudfront with Geolocation policy vs Route53](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54003091/aws-cloudfront-with-geolocation-policy-vs-route53)

Comment: Why do you create three different CloudFront distributions? CloudFronts purpose is to direct users to its closest location. So what are you trying to achieve by using three CloudFront distributions?

Comment: @Dunedan I'm going to have users in Asia, Europe, and NA.  The goal is to reduce latency by having 3 different CloudFront distributions.

Comment: That's the purpose of CloudFront and a single CloudFront distribution is absolutely sufficient to achieve that.